# Grab IDs of products from WP_Query via a filter whilst it's running on a template file

Tags: php, wordpress

In one of my template files, I am running the standard WP_Query and loop etc. This is not within the product archive etc, just a regular custom template.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
); ?>

<?php $post_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
        
        <?php if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                etc....
```

From my filters.php file, I want to hook into that WP_Query and grab the IDs returned. I suspect it's a `pre_get_posts` approach but I need it to be focusing on the WP_Query which I am running to get products. Elsewhere on the site are other WP_Query's being ran.

How can I hook into the currently running WP_Query for `product` post type and grab the IDs. I don't want to do this within the loop in the template file.

Comment: The purpose of `pre_get_posts` is to manipulate the query itself, not to handle its results. (That won't even be possible, the query has not been executed yet at the point that filter runs.)

Comment: One way to get the IDs would be to access the `posts` property of the query object, that is an array of posts - and then use `array_column` to extract only the post IDs. But the query still needs to have executed first - so if your reason for asking is that you need those IDs somewhere else, before the template code actually executes, that won't work either. Would rather be a pretty sure sign, that you should not be making this query inside the template file to begin with. (Which in theory, you of course never should.)